# Facebook like box is overwriting a youtube iframe

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, iframe, youtube

The problem is that I have a youtube iframe and a facebook iframe for facebook's like box. The like box is showing in both places. How do I fix this?

[image]

Here is the HTML as is shows up in the page source:

```
<div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/YerNjFjBrOo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div> 
</div> 
    </div> 
</div> 

<div class="vc_span4 wpb_column column_container">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <div class="a13-separator wpb_content_element separator_align_center separator_align_center single_dots"><h3 style="font-weight:normal;"><span>Cost Effective and Low Maintenance</span></h3>
<div></div></div>
<div class="a13-separator full_width empty" style="margin-top:10px;"><div></div><br class="clear" /></div>

<div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <p>Concrete borders are a cost effective, low maintenance way to create permanent finishing touches to your lawn, reducing time consuming yard work and increasing property values.  The various curb styles that Curb-It, Inc. offers will reduce edging, trimming and time spent maintaining the landscaping. Concrete curbs are an attractive and durable investment in your property that will last for years to come.</p>

    </div> 
</div> 
<div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FCurbit&amp;width=300&amp;height=558&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;header=false&amp;stream=true&amp;show_border=false&amp;appId=116642065097325" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:300px; height:558px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
    </div> 
</div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or link us to your live page, I would like to some inspecting

Comment: I was not able to replicate this in a fiddle. And I ended up reverting to youtube's old implementation method which fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found a reason for this, but the solution to fix the problem was reverting to youtube's old embed code rather than using the iFrame.